# loop logistic regression in R

Tags: r, loops, logistic-regression

I am very new to R.  I have a huge dataset containing over 500K genetic sites. I'm struggling to loop logistic regression through my independent variables. The data only has 10 rows (10 patients) but have 500K+ columns (genetic sites and phenotype).

I need to loop to run each genetic site once, each model would be like phenotype= each genetic site + age +gender. (genetic site is the only variable different in each model).

How can I create the loop?
I tried:

```
logistic_regression <- lapply(mydata [,1:n], function(x) glm(outcome ~ geneticsite[,x] + age + gender , family=binomial,data=mydata))
```

I keep getting a warning message saying `geneticsite` is not found.
Can someone please help me with it?
Thanks!

---

More details:
This is a pilot study on a very rare phenotype, so we were only able to test 10 patients. We would like to have OR (geneticsite) and P values (geneticsite) as the output.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to restructure your data so that each genetic site was it's own variable and then you can use GROUP_BY and tidymodels to do the regression in a single call?

Comment: I think this is the answer you need here: https://coderedirect.com/questions/523195/map-tidymodels-process-to-a-list-group-by-or-nest

Comment: first of all a multivariable model of 10 observations and 2-3 predictors may not be very stable, plus what are you going to do with 500k models? if you have a vector of each site variable name, you could do the following: `sites <- c('site1', 'site2'); lr <- lapply(sites, function(x) glm(reformulate(c('age', 'gender', x), 'outcome'), family = binomial, data = mydata))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example data I used

```
mydata <- 
  data.frame(
    GeneticSite = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
    GeneticSite1 = c(2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3),
    Age = c(17, 52, 19, 18, 62, 53, 41, 24),
    Gender = c(1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1),
    Outcome = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1)
  )
```

I then used `library(dplyr)` pivot the data longer so we can group by all the Genetic Sites. I then create the linear regression function Age + Gender and use `summary` to get all the coefficients which I use to calculate the OR values.

```
Linear_regression <- mydata %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("GeneticSite"),
               names_to = ".value",
               names_pattern = "(^GeneticSite)") %>% 
  group_by(GeneticSite) %>% 
  do(Reg = lm(Outcome ~ Age + Gender, data = .)) %>%
  summarise(GeneticSite,rsq = summary(Reg)$r.squared,
            Intercept_Estimate = summary(Reg)$coefficients[1],
            Age_Estimate = summary(Reg)$coefficients[2],
            Gender_Estimate = summary(Reg)$coefficients[3],
            Intercept_Std_Error = summary(Reg)$coefficients[4],
            Age_Std_Error = summary(Reg)$coefficients[5],
            Gender_Std_Error = summary(Reg)$coefficients[6],
            Intercept_t_value = summary(Reg)$coefficients[7],
            Age_t_value = summary(Reg)$coefficients[8],
            Gender_t_value = summary(Reg)$coefficients[9],
            Intercept_p_value = summary(Reg)$coefficients[10],
            Age_p_value = summary(Reg)$coefficients[11],
            Gender_p_value = summary(Reg)$coefficients[12]) %>%
  mutate(OR_Estimate = exp(Intercept_Estimate)/(1+exp(Intercept_Estimate))) %>% 
  mutate(OR_Age = exp(Age_Estimate)/(1+exp(Age_Estimate))) %>% 
  mutate(OR_Gender = exp(Age_Estimate)/(1+exp(Age_Estimate)))
```

This is how I knew how to label each column

```
> summary(y)$coefficients

             Estimate     Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  1.750000e+00  0.3331066  5.253574e+00 0.0001558944
x$Age        9.688771e-18  0.0151608  6.390673e-16 1.0000000000
x$Gender    -7.500000e-01  0.5211766 -1.439052e+00 0.1737764924
```

example output:

```
"GeneticSite","rsq","Intercept_Estimate","Age_Estimate","Gender_Estimate","Intercept_Std_Error","Age_Std_Error","Gender_Std_Error","Intercept_t_value","Age_t_value","Gender_t_value","Intercept_p_value","Age_p_value","Gender_p_value","OR_Estimate","OR_Age","OR_Gender"
"1",1,0.6,1.75,-9.13466064460698e-18,-0.749999999999999,0.537118251352767,0.0244460541141712,0.840372000724438,3.25812797385401,-3.73666056777305e-16,-0.892461908956351,0.0224922711346427,1,0.413031579096883,0.85195280196831,0.5,0.5
"2",2,1,2,9.08261087251563e-18,-1,4.20114922415409e-16,1.48859041349867e-17,5.45878506026351e-16,4760602143102169,0.610148418944103,-1831909461464908,1.33726733138161e-16,0.651229019050892,3.47517050246851e-16,0.880797077977882,0.5,0.5
"3",3,0.351351351351351,1.21621621621622,-0.0270270270270271,0.351351351351353,2.0286480005184,0.162162162162162,5.15550724280418,0.599520575233073,-0.166666666666667,0.0681506852389265,0.656182728286001,0.894863086577493,0.956680908817521,0.771396988381907,0.493243654508354,0.493243654508354
```

Comment: With geneticSite being individual columns that doesn't work, need to add a pivot_longer() to the solution IMO.

Comment: oh true thank you!

Comment: This gives correlation and corresponding p values right? I'm looking for OR and P values particularly for between genetics sites and outcome (which is a binary variable 1 vs 0). Thanks!